# How to define prerequisite functions in Midje?

Tags: clojure, tdd, midje

I should start by saying I'm new to Clojure, and FP in general. I've been reading the documentation about how to define prerequisites in Midje, but I can't make sense of some of it.

My understanding was that to do top-down TDD, you're supposed to start by writing a test in your test module, with an `unfinished` statement at the top that 'declares' all the prerequisite functions you haven't defined yet. Then you can fiddle with those prerequisite functions in the `provided` function within your test (describing their return values and such).

My confusion lies in how you're supposed to get your actual source module to recognize the prerequisite functions. Here's a very simple and contrived example I'll use to illustrate my meaning:

```
    ;;; in my run_game_test module

    (ns clojure-ttt.run-game-test
      (:require [midje.sweet :refer :all]
                [clojure-ttt.run-game :refer [start-game]]))

    (unfinished do-turns)

    (fact "`start-game` returns whatever `do-turns` returns"
      (start-game) => ..winner..
      (provided
        (do-turns) => ..winner..))
```

And then to make the test fail properly, I just write a stub of a function in my `run_game` module.

```
    (ns clojure-ttt.run-game)

    (defn start-game
      [])
```

So far so good. I run the tests and they fail because:
a) `do-turns` isn't getting called
b) `start-game` isn't returning anything.

So now to make the test pass, by changing `start-game` to call and return `(do-turns)`. For the record, `do-turns` is a hypothetical prerequisite function that I'm going to get from a not-yet-existing module--which, as I understand, is how top-down TDD works.

```
    (defn start-game
      []
      (do-turns))
```

Now, understandably, I get a huge error; Clojure can't resolve the symbol `do-turns`. So I thought, maybe if I `(declare do-turns)` at the top I could keep it from blowing up. No, I get a different error because I'm trying to call an unbound function.

I tried a couple other ways of getting Clojure to recognize `do-turns` but it seems like the `unfinished` statement is giving it issues. Am I just using `unfinished` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Midje docs](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Describing-one-checkable%27s-prerequisites):

> `unfinished` is similar to Clojure's `declare` in that it can take multiple arguments and define a var for each one of them. Unlike declare, it binds the var to a function that blows up if called

So when you do `(unfinished do-turns)` and then call it with `(do-turns)` an exception is thrown:

> Error `#'do-turns` [the var] has no implementation, but it was called like this:
>   `(do-turns)` midje.util.exceptions/user-error (exceptions.clj:13)

You can fix this by removing the `(unfinished do-turns)` part and provide an implementation of `do-turns`. E.g.,

```
(ns clojure-ttt.run-game)

(defn do-turns)
  [])

(defn start-game
  []
  (do-turns))
```

and refer it in your test

```
(ns clojure-ttt.run-game-test
  (:require [midje.sweet :refer :all]
            [clojure-ttt.run-game :refer [start-game do-turns]])) ; <- do-turns

;; Remove `(unfinished do-turns)` since it is no longer unfinished

(fact "`start-game` returns whatever `do-turns` returns"
  (start-game) => ..winner..
  (provided
   (do-turns) => ..winner..)) 
;; => returns true
```

Note that when you have provided an implementation of `do-turns`, `(unfinished do-turns)` will throw an exception since an implementation already exists, so it is removed.

Now you have shown that a call to `(start-game)` returns what `(do-turns`) returns.

Comment: Thanks, that works. My only concern is that, if I put `do-turns` into a different namespace, does that mean I'll have to import into my test module both the namespace where `start-game` lives and the namespace where `do-turns` lives? In OOP I make a point of only importing the class under test into the corresponding test directory, and mocking out the dependencies. Is that pattern just not possible in Clojure?

Comment: Yes, if `do-turns` and `start-game` are in different namespaces you need to import both namespaces or give the fully qualified name like `clojure-ttt.other-namespace/do-turns`. `provided` makes use of [`with-redefs`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs) and you need to access the var to overwrite it. If you want to depend on abstractions you can use protocols.